# Sylvester equation over quaternion

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, sylvester-equation

How to solve the Sylvester equation $$ax + xb = c$$ over quaternion? I tried to consider operator $$D = a^2 + a\cdot(b+\overline{b}) + b \cdot \overline{b} $$ and calculate $Dx$. But it didn't help.

P.S: What is the general meaning of this equation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by general meaning? It means Sylvester's equation, not in $M_n(K)$, but in the quaternion algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [paper](http://conf.uni-ruse.bg/bg/docs/cp09/6.1/6.1-8.pdf). I'd interpret $ax+xb=c$ as an equation asking for a quaternion $x=x_0+ x_1i+x_2j+x_3 k$, given quaternions $a$, $b$, and $c$ in a similar way. Write out this equation component wise, and obtain linear equations for the $x_i$. For the existence of a unique solution there will be some assumptions on the parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$.